# Render .mht files dynamically without load/iframe/embed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I have .mht files that are stored on a folder on my server. This folder has a rule in `.htaccess` that only `localhost` is allowed inside.

I need to render files on my website depending on user actions.
`<iframe>` and `<embed>` and jquery `.load()` won't work as the request doesn't come from `localhost`.

I'm trying to get the data of the file via a phpscript and an ajax call :

PHP:

```
$file = htmlentities(filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), ENT_QUOTES);
$content = file_get_contents(".".$file);
$return = array("content" => $content);
echo json_encode($return);
```

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('queries.php',{q: 'getFile', url: file},
        function(data){
            $('#file_panel').html(data.content);
        }
);
```

But it only displays the content of the file, it doesn't render it. Any suggestion to get it rendered?

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible unless you use an `<iframe>`. Browsers won't parse HTML & MHT within the same page.

Try this,

> PHP File

```
$file = htmlentities(filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), ENT_QUOTES);
echo file_get_contents(".".$file);
```

> JS

```
$("#frame").attr("src", "queries.php?url="+file);
```

Comment: Let me know if you don't understand any of my suggestion.